# Как работает addressof функция?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{}; 

  template <class T>
    T * addressof(T & v)
    {
      return reinterpret_cast<T *>(& const_cast<char&>(reinterpret_cast<const volatile char &>(v)));
    }

int main()
{
    A a;
    std::cout<<&a<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<addressof(a)<<std::endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

> output:
>
> 0x7a9ba88cd79f
>
> 0x7a9ba88cd79f

Данная функция возвращает адрес объекта, интересно, как она работает?

Comment: Так реализация же есть у вас в коде

Comment: О чем вопрос? О том, как работают С++ касты? Или о чем-то другом?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вопрос, как я понимаю, в расшифровке всех этих кастов, и почему используются именно они. А суть самого `std::addressof`, чтобы иметь возможность получить адрес объекта, даже если для типа объекта перегружен оператор взятия адреса `operator&`.

Первый каст `reinterpret_cast<const volatile char&>(arg)))` делает низкоуровневое преобразование к символьному типу `char` (минимально адресуемый тип, т.к. его размер по определению равен единице) с добавлением объекту `const` и `volative` специфичности. Если не добавить `const` и `volatile`, то не получится работать с `const` и `volatile` объектами соответственно.

Второй каст `const_cast<char&>` убирает свежедобавленные `const` и `volatile`, чтобы подготовить плацдарм для третьего каста. Тут ещё можно заметить взятие адреса `&`, которое уже не может быть перегружено, ибо оперирует со встроенным типом `char` и даёт в итоге указатель на `char`.

Итоговый каст `reinterpret_cast<T*>` собственно приводит тип к необходимому типу объекта.

Comment: Разве оператор взятия адреса можно перегрузить?

Comment: @Qwertiy Можно.